# Python-magic not recognized while trying to import in Django

Tags: file-type, python-magic

I am trying to check the file type of the uploaded data using magic but pylance is not recognizing it
I keep getting this error [pylance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqaRM.png)

I installed python-magic 0.4.27
My python version is- 3.9
Django-version- 4.1.3

I tried adding python-magic to Installed Apps in Settings after Installing it locally on my command prompt
I also Installed python-magic-bin-0.4.14 but it still gives me that error.
[pylance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obDZn.png)

Answer (score 0):

python-magic is a Python interface to the libmagic file type identification library. libmagic identifies file types by checking their headers according to a predefined list of file types.

You have install in virtual environment with "pip install python-magic"